# toString method with call on a number

Tags: javascript

I do not understand whats happening here. How does the code print 11?

```
var z = 5;
 console.log(z.toString.call(16)); //output 16
```

```
var z = 5;
 console.log(z.toString.call(16,15));// output 11
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument (if there is one) is the radix (base) that you want it to be converted with.

You've specified that it should use radix 15, so the value 16 is converted to the string "11" (1*15 + 1).

Answer (score 1):

The [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) methods takes a parameter for the radix and will convert the number to the base supplied as that argument:

```js
var decimal = 10;

var binary = decimal.toString(2);

console.log(binary)
```

When you use [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the *first* argument you supply is the `this` context for the method. In essence, you change the starting number:

```js
var num = 10;

var otherNumber = 42;

console.log(num.toString.call(otherNumber));
//          ^^^               ^^^^^^^^^^^
//ignored ___|                     |
//the new `this` __________________|
```

When you supply the *second* argument to `.call` that becomes the *first* argument for the method.

So, with this in mind, when you call `z.toString.call(16,15)` then `z` is of no relevance, you are essentially calling

```js
console.log((16).toString(15))
```

And in base-15, the decimal `16` is indeed converted to `11`.